# Banshee crashes while rescaning the library

Tags: banshee

Everytime I try to make a rescan, Banshee keeps crashing. The songs it was able to discover are added to library list on the next start up of Banshee. Then, it crashes again if I am to try rescan.

Any ideas?

Comment: This should be reported as a bug report to bugzilla.gnome.org

Comment: Is it always just adding the same list of music, or does it discover more each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common bug with banshee's database. To solve it, delete your banshee.db in `~/.config/Banshee-1`. The next time you scan it should work without crashing.

**EDIT: forgot to mention, you should make sure that you export playlists when you create them as they are stored in the database.**

Comment: Play counts, skip counts, ratings, and a lot more are also stored in the database, so do this with care.  IIRC, the crash usually happens when Banshee tries update the smart playlists while rescanning.  There's an open bug report for this, and even a working patch, I think.

Comment: @MichaelMS: yes all of that data is stored in the database, but also in the files (so long as you enable the option to write metadata to the files, which you should do).

Answer (score 4):

Try running banshee from a terminal and then running a scan. This should output the error that is causing the program to crash. Without this, theres not much we can do.

Hope this helps,
Bodsda

Comment: for those trying to find out a bit more try banshee --debug, as that will produce a bit more detail and normally gives an answer at the point of the crash.